# PHP Functions only working in Chrome

Tags: php, internet-explorer, function, google-chrome, browser

I have a normal html form with text inputs etc.
I have normal Function to check username and password against database to log the user in.

My register and login pages everything is working perfectly in Chrome, but [ie](/questions/tagged/ie) and 
[firefox](/questions/tagged/firefox) etc. It refreshes the page in all browsers except for chrome.

I've uploaded the site onto free webhost just for you to see.
[here](http://vuilhonde.hostzi.com)

This is what the php login looks like :

```
    function login()
    {   
    if(isset($_POST["login"]))
    {
    connectDB();
    $username = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["username"]);
    $password = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["password"]);




    $result = mysql_query("SELECT username FROM users WHERE username = '$username' AND             password = '$password'"); 
    if(!$result)
    {
        die("query failed" . mysql_error());
    }
    else
    {
        $count = mysql_num_rows($result);
        if($count > 0)
        {
            $_SESSION['loggedIn'] = $username;
            echo "<script>window.location='http://vuilhonde.hostzi.com/';</script>";
            header("Location:http://vuilhonde.hostzi.com/");
        }   
        else
        {
            return "Login failed.</br>* invalid username or password.";
        }
    }
    mysql_free_result($result);
}
}
```

Comment: Have you tried just removing the `echo "<script> ... </script>"`? Also, consider adding `exit;` after the `header()` statement.

Comment: I tried that now, still same problem.

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Answer (score 2):

You should never echo any output *before* sending a header. How a browser handles that might be the cause of your problem.

Comment: Ok I sorted that out and still doing the same. Thanks for the advice though

Comment: Do you have any output at all before the code above? You can't have **any** output, even a space will make the header function be ignored

Comment: Its not just the header not working, Im running this code on a new machine that doesn't even have the databases on yet so in chrome when i say login, it echos all the my_sql errors because of DB not existing. In firefox and ie, it still just refreshes the page when clicking login. Instead of echo'ing the errors/exceptions

Answer (score 2):

A few issues:

1. The `Location:` header needs a space after the colon, so it should be `` `Location: http://whatever ``
2. The `Location:` header is only followed by a browser when the response has an appropriate status code, e.g. HTTP 301, 302, or 303. Right now you're sending 200, which means the browser should display the content of the document.
3. PHP's `header` function only works properly if it's sent BEFORE any resource content. You're using `echo` before, so it won't work right. In some PHP configurations this will cause an error to be displayed.
4. However the `<script>` code is invalid HTML and browsers might not execute it (you're missing the required `<html>` element and its necessary children.
5. You should be hashing your passwords in your database, not storing them as plaintext. Also you're performing a case-insensitive predicate.

Comment: The first two issues are, in varying degrees, invalid.

Comment: Yes. The second issue is completely invalid as the PHP and/or Apache postprocessing of headers will add an appropriate HTTP status based on the added location header. The first issue is a real one, but might be fixed by the same postprocessing. But the list of issues in the code still is long.

Comment: @Sven The first one is bogus too. Have a look at [RFC 2616](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2616.txt), section 4.2, second paragraph.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a missing file in the head section, for example the

```
<script language="javascript" src="javascript/javascript.js"></script>
```

if this file does not exist, it can cause some browsers to do a page - refresh. i'll try to reproduce this bug (update coming soon) or you can test it yourself by removing that line and tell us whats the result. (if you do this please tell us your browsers version)

also if that

```
echo "<script>window.location='http://vuilhonde.hostzi.com/';</script>";
```

happens outside the `<body>`, or inside the `<head>` it **WILL** cause firefox to refresh.

Comment: I have that code in the header. And the file does exist